# Google Play beta testing

Tags: google-play, testing

I made a game I wish to upload to Google Play and I faced the options

- Production
- Beta testing
- Alpha testing

I made the game all alone and I think it is complete, was tested on multiple physical as well as virtual devices, all well and good.

As I'm alone and would consider the game finished, does it make sense to upload beta instead of production? I'm not in connection with anybody, so I don't think anyone would try and play the game (apart from meself). Or would some testers employed by Google test the apps if they are submitted to open beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *alpha* and *beta* test stages only make sense to use if you plan to do any testing in them, Google will not do any testing for you on your application just because it goes through those stages.

Note that this does not mean you need to have staff or employed people testing your application, both *alpha* and *beta* can be run as open testing, i.e. people can download and run the application from Play just like any other app if the stage is open, but the download page comes with a notice saying the application is still in testing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Well in my case I have no-one ask for testing and I tested it as much as I could while in development and after, so it makes no sense to upload as alpha/beta I think.